# Uso de comando artisan vendor:publish

Tags: laravel, artisan

Estoy tratando de entender qué hace, y cómo se puede sacar partido el comando `php artisan vendor:publish`. He estado revisando la documentación de Laravel, pero no encuentro nada concreto al respecto. Donde se ponen ejemplos (en notificaciones y en otras partes), la documentación asume que ya sabes lo que hace y por qué está ahí. Es muy escueta.

Agradeceré que alguien me indique alguna web o material con explicaciones lo más detalladas posibles para entender este comando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando instalamos un paquete de terceros en Laravel:

```
composer require vendor\package-name
```

Tenemos un comando, nos permitirá hacer el trabajo de la inclusión de recursos asociados a dicho paquete.

Me refiero a que si necesitamos instalar un paquete cuyo funcionamiento dependeda de archivos tales como:

- de estilos
- de creación de migraciones
- de creación de vistas
- de archivos js
- de configuración
- re gistro de logs
- etc.

Todos estos podrán ser agregados a nuestro proyecto al momento de realizar el comando:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="VendorName\PackageName\NameServiceProvider"
```

Posterior a realizar este paso si tienes tu proyecto teniendo un seguimiento por algún controlador de versionamiento como *Git* te tendría que notificar que en determinadas rutas **(las cuales pueden variar dependiendo de la finalidad de dicho paquete usado)** hay archivos que no tienen seguimiento o están *untracked* lo cual indica que la acción anterior ha generado uno o varios de estos nuevos dentro de tu proyecto.

Lo anterior lo puedes comprobar por que en la consola te debe aparecer una notificación similar a la siguiente:

```
Copied File [\vendor\package\package-name\ruta\archivo.foo] To [\ruta\archivo.foo]
Publishing complete.
```

Como tal este comando te va a permitir:

- Anular y publicar de nuevo recursos asociados a algún paquete con la bandera **`flag`**
- Publicar los recursos de un paquete de un proveedor específico con la bandera **`--provider=[AQUI EL PROVEEDOR]`**
- Indicar si el paquete deberá esta r disponible para desarrollo o producción con la bandera **`--env[AQUI EL AMBIENTE]`**

Incluso puedes tener a tu disposición una lista de los proveedores y etiquetas disponibles para que las publiques con solo ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

**Recursos**

- [Comando **`vendor:publish`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/packages#resources)

Answer (score 3):

Una explicación sencilla: este comando permite copiar directorios y/o archivos desde la ubicación original de un paquete de un tercero (carpeta vendor) a nuestro proyecto, normalmente con uno, dos o tres fines:

- Configurar el paquete instalado.
- Personalizar/modificar el paquete instalado.
- Hacer que funcione correctamente el paquete (es posible que se instalen archivos en la carpeta public que no podrían ser leídos de otra forma).

Normalmente es el creador del paquete quien define qué es "publicable" o en otras palabras, qué se puede copiar a las carpetas del proyecto.